# Rails Stripe Integration Error on Final Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Stripe integrated and it's supposed to set up so that users can become a seller and sell products. Other users can buy them, the platform takes a fee, and the seller gets the rest. When I try to do a purchase, I get a 500 internal server error. The logs tell me the error is this:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError (You cannot create a destination charge on a connected account without the `card_payments` capability enabled. Use transfer_data[destination] to create a destination charge for a connected account with the `platform_payments` capability.)
```

I do not understand how to fix this.

transaction.rb

```
  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
    @transaction.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @seller = @listing.user
    @transaction.listing_id = @listing.id
    @transaction.seller_id = @seller.id

    @total_amount = (@listing.price * 100).to_i
    @charged_fee = (@listing.price * 15 - 30).to_i

    charge_error = nil

    if @transaction.valid?
      begin
        if !current_user.stripe_id.blank?
          customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
        else
          customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :email => params[:stripeEmail],
            :source  => params[:stripeToken]
          )
          current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
          current_user.save
        end

        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
            {
                :customer => customer.id,
                :amount      => @total_amount,
                :description => @listing.title,
                :currency => 'usd',
                :destination => @seller.uid,
                :application_fee => @charged_fee
            },
        )

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        charge_error = e.message
      end
      if charge_error
        flash[:error] = charge_error
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :new }
        end
      else
        @transaction.save

        Activity.create!(item_id: @listing.id, user_id: current_user.id,
                                  activity_type: "purchase")

        Notification.create!(listing_id: @listing.id, 
                                recipient_id: @listing.user_id, notified_by_id: current_user.id, 
                                notification_type: "purchase")
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to purchases_path, notice: 'Transaction successful. You may now download this.' }
        end
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = 'one or more errors in your order'
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

[StripeSettingsPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6gyw.png)

1. Can you check your Stripe settings? Stripe-> Settings -> Connect.
2. "Complete your platform profile" - if you didn't yet
   2.1 if you just started it on the first step you have to choose a "Capability": Platform Payments or Card Payments.

[start platform picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P020.png)

Comment: Hi, yeah it shows that both card and platform payments are selected.